# Is this meta.TP post still extant?

Tags: discussion, site-salvage

The question [Papers and preprints worth reading, Jan-midFeb 2012](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27129/papers-and-preprints-worth-reading-jan-midfeb-2012) is a [resource-recommendation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation) question imported from the now-defunct Theoretical Physics site. I don't think it is constructive or that it should be reopened, and it is far from being in line with the current books policy. However, I'm quite curious as to whether it's part of a series and what the motivation for it, and discussions about it, were.

The question cites a meta.TP thread ["Journal club-like thing"](http://meta.theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/234/journal-club-like-thing) but the link is dead. Is it still possible to access that page?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, just not very usable: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bDHu1.png

Comment: Download the A51.SE data dump for TP.SE